# Grails Plugin project import javax.websocket cannot be resolved

Tags: grails, plugins

Hi I am working on a project in Grails which needs to import these files-

```
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason.CloseCode;
import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.MessageHandler;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.Session;
```

So these imports were working perfectly when I was working on a Grails project but now I have been told to shift the project to a Grails plugin project which will be imported in the main project, so now in this case when I try to import the above mentioned files it shows me an error that `The import javax.websocket cannot be resolved.`

I tried to fiddle around with some dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy but was unable to resolve this problem. If anyone has tried it please let me know how to import the files of `javax.websocket.*` in a Grails Plugin Project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably the unnecessary semicolons.

In the unlikely case that it's more involved than that, make sure that you're working outside of an IDE to reduce the number of active variables. Get it working in Grails first, then get it working in GGTS/IntelliJ/etc.

The process is *exactly* the same for a plugin as for an app; add a dependency for a jar in `BuildConfig.groovy` containing those classes, and run `grails compile` to trigger dependency resolution. This will download the jar to your local Maven/Ivy/Gradle cache if it hasn't already, and add it to the app's classpath.

In this case, the confusion is coming from the fact that these classes are in `tomcat-embed-websocket-<version>.jar` that is in the classpath of your application because you kept the default dependency on the Tomcat plugin, and apparently it's not a dependency of your plugin (and it probably should not be). It was coincidentally working in the app, but would have started to fail if you removed the Tomcat plugin dependency (e.g. to use Jetty instead).

To get this working, add this to your `dependencies` block and run `grails compile`:

```
compile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
```

You should also consider using the [spring-websocket](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket) plugin instead of doing everything manually.

Comment: Thankyou so much Burt. The semicolons were there as they were java files. I tried converting them to groovy, removing semicolons but nothing changed. Also tried it without IDE and it was the same. Tried putting dependencies and plugins that you mentioned. I actually tried them few times and some times the imports were getting solved and sometimes not. Out of curosity I was trying different combinations of these sometimes in grails interactive mode on command line and sometimes without that. I would say it never resolved the imports in interactive mode. Will try it in weekend and let you know.

Comment: And yes I was able to solve my problem thanks to you. Hit and trial as mentioned above will be if someone else faces same problem he will be able to look up the solution here.

Comment: I was kidding about the semicolons, but please review [this style guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+style+and+language+feature+guidelines+for+Java+developers). I'm glad it's working - what was the actual solution?

Comment: The `compile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'` is the actual solution. While the `spring-websocket` plugin did not solve the imports. Also, bit out of scope, but would like to mention that while using grails interactive mode I found that each time I updated the BuildConfig.groovy file I had to exit and start the interactive mode again for changes to take place when running `compile` command. While the non-interactive mode works perfectly. Thank you so much Burt for stoping by and replying to my question.